# rails ajax detect form parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using ajax to submit a form with two buttons. I then detect which button is pressed by using params[:commit] in the controller. I am also using jQuery's AjaxComplete function to do some manipulation on the front end. My question is how do I get access to the value of my commit button within jquery's Ajax Complete function so that I can tell which button was pressed without going through the controller?

For example, I'm already kind of doing something similar where I check the url to see which ajax request was sent and then doing some action, now i'd like to drill down deeper and see what parameters were being sent with the ajax request (code is coffeescript)

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete (event, xhr, settings) ->
    if settings.url.indexOf('mode=2') > 0
      $('#nav_tabs').show();
```

Comment: can attach any data you need to the xhr object in beforeSend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the `settings` argument passed into the `ajaxComplete` handler.
Depending on your version of jQuery, you may be able to directly access the `settings.data` POJO. If you can't, you can pretty much get exactly what you want by just playing around with `settings.url`.

For example, let's say you were performing a GET to http://www.google.com with the `data` object `{ herp: "derp", karp: "larp"}`. This data will get appended to the URL as a query param. Let's mess with it!

```
// load the URL of the request
var u = new URL(settings.url);
var params = u.search.replace("?", "").split("&").map(
    function(currVal) {
        var parts = currVal.split("=");
        var resp = {};
        resp[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        return resp;
});
// params now contains an array of { key: value } mappings for the request params.
// now, lets merge them!
var merged_params = {};
for (var i : params) {
    merged_params[i] = params[i];
}
// now merged_params is a POJO with the original keys&values of the data sent to the server.
```